# Why is the function receiving original value when I have incremented it during the parameter passing?

Tags: javascript, function

Let's say this is my factory function to generate an object.

```
const generateObjectWithId = (id,value) => (
 {id,value}
);
```

I have declared an Id before I generated the object and then I incremented it using `++`

```
let currentId = 0;
const object = generateObjectWithId(currentId++,"sample");
```

Result:

```
console.log(currentId) => 1
console.log(object) => {id:0,value:"sample"}
```

`currentId` got incremented to 1 but the `object` I received from the factory function is with id 0.

I've fixed it with incrementing the currentId before passing in the parameter and worked right now.

My fix:

```
let currentId = 0;
currentId++; //or currentId = currentId + 1;
const object = generateObjectWithId(currentId,"sample");
```

But I need someone's help to explain me why incrementing inside the parameter won't work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `currentId++` will *first* return the old value *then* increment it. If you use `++currentId` you'd *first* increment the value *then* return the new one.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone for enlightening me. appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`currentId++`, this increments the counter after the passing
while `++currentId` increments the counter and then pass it

Answer (score 0):

It will increment the index after passing it to the function. If you used `++currentId` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`currentId++` means increment after the execution. I think what you need is `++currentId`, which means increment then execute.